# SQL Server 2008 AND/OR operators and parentheses

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, where-clause, sql-like

I am having a bit of trouble with AND/OR operators. It's easy stuff, but I'm having trouble with the following scenario:

```
WHERE      (ID = '111') OR (charge_desc LIKE '%garn%') OR
                      (charge_desc LIKE '%levy%') OR
                      (charge_desc LIKE '%exe%')
```

Basically, I am trying to find the keywords based **only** on ID 111. However, what's happening with the current query is that it looks for those keywords based on a bunch of different IDs instead. I've tried to manipulate the parenthesis, and I see the issue. Because it can't be "111 OR LIKE XYZ..." but it can't be AND either because if you do AND, then it looks for that ID based on EXACTLY those 3 criteria.

I am looking to do ID 111 and look for `garn` or `levy` or `exe` - not "AND" but it should be every variation that comes up but ONLY for 111.

I hope this makes sense. I feel its something with the parenthesis.

I just tried this:

```
WHERE ID = 111
HAVING garn or levy or exe
```

Forgive my lack of syntax there. :)

Comment: I think I got it...

WHERE ID = 111

HAVING garn OR levy OR exe

Is that correct? Or will I be missing entries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you absolutely **must** have `id = 111` then this is an **`and`** relationship, not an `or` relationship. You can then have a series of `or` operators between the other conditions:

```
WHERE ID = '111' AND
      (charge_desc LIKE '%garn%' OR
       charge_desc LIKE '%levy%' OR
       charge_desc LIKE '%exe%')
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the parenthesis.

Let's look at this scenario:

```
WHERE      (ID = '111') OR (charge_desc LIKE '%garn%') OR
                      (charge_desc LIKE '%levy%') OR
                      (charge_desc LIKE '%exe%')
```

You are saying where ID = 111 OR Charg_Desc like garn...etc.

```
WHERE      (ID = '111') AND 
                      (charge_desc LIKE '%garn%' OR
                      charge_desc LIKE '%levy%' OR
                      charge_desc LIKE '%exe%')
```

Now, you're saying WHERE ID = 111 AND the following conditional OR is applied to bring in the additional match. Remember, the match is in addition to the ID match.